# C# WPF - Click through image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-8.0

I have a WPF application on .NET 8 where a window is loaded like this:

```cs
var myWindow = new Window
{
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
    AllowsTransparency = true,
    Background = Brushes.Transparent,
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized,
    Topmost = true,
    ShowInTaskbar = false
};

myWindow.Show();
```

After this a `.png` file is loaded into the content of `myWindow`

```cs
myImage = new Image
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Resources/myImage.png", UriKind.Relative)),
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    Width = 50,
    Height = 50,
    Opactity = 0.5,
    Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.None,
    IsHitTestVisible = false
};

myWindow.Content = myImage;
```

What i need to do is to click through the image (image should be ignored).

Currently the image blocks all clicks for any layer behind the image.

`IsHitTestVisible = false` seems not to work here...

Comment: Since Window doesn’t have a Click event what are you actually doing? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#events

Comment: Try if the behavior changes without setting AllowTransparency

Comment: I'd probably retemplate a button and put the button in the window, picture in the button. You get a bindable Icommand then.

Comment: I just want to display a image with some opacity that does not hinder mouse clicks...

Comment: so let's say the image overlays the desktop then I want the desktop icons to be still clickable

Comment: You would have to manually filter the mouse click at OS level. Use Win32 API to  establish a message loop hook. Then detect whether the click was targeting your application by checking the screen coordinates. If this was your application, pass through the event message (don't handle it) so that other windows can process it.

Comment: You should add those details in the OP, instead of leaving them in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i could solve it using the Win32 API like so:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var myWindow = new Window
        {
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            AllowsTransparency = true,
            Background = Brushes.Transparent,
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized,
            Topmost = true,
            ShowInTaskbar = false
        };

        myWindow.Show();

        var myImage = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Resources/myImage.png", UriKind.Relative)),
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Width = 50,
            Height = 50,
            Opacity = 0.5,
            Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.None,
            IsHitTestVisible = false
        };

        myWindow.Content = myImage;

        // Make the window ignore mouse click events
        var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow);
        SetWindowLong(helper.Handle, -20, 0x80000 | 0x20);
    }
}
```